# Só envia um produto dentro do email

Tags: php, phpmailer

Insiro em 3 tabelas diferentes e quando a checkbox **não** é diferente de vazio envia um email ao responsável. Está tudo a funcionar corretamente. Vou mostrar o código:

```
$Carro = $_POST['Carro'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Carro"]);$i++) { 
$car = $_POST['Carro'][$i];
$selecionado = $_POST['Selecionado'][$i];  

if( $selecionado != ""){

$selecionado = $selecionado == "on" ? "X" : "";
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Registolistagem (Carro, Selecionado) VALUES ('$car', '$selecionado')");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;

}
}

$colaborador = $_POST['Colaborador'];
for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Colaborador"]);$i++) { 
$col = $_POST['Colaborador'][$i];
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Registolistagem2 (IdLista, Colaborador, Data) VALUES ('$last_id', '$col', '".date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')."')");
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2); 

}

$Produto = $_POST['Produto'];

for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST["Produto"]);$i++) { 
$prod = $_POST['Produto'][$i];
$sim = $_POST['Sim'][$i]; 
$nao = $_POST['Nao'][$i]; 
$obsevacao = $_POST['Observacao'][$i];  


 $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Registolistagem1 (IdList, Produto, Sim, Obsevacao) VALUES ('$last_id', '$prod', '$sim', '$obsevacao')");
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);

if($sim != "Sim"){

require ("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require ("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

# Inicia a classe PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();

# Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
$mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; # Endereço do servidor SMTP, na WebHS basta usar localhost caso a conta de email esteja na mesma máquina de onde esta a correr este código, caso contrário altere para o seu desejado ex: mail.nomedoseudominio.pt
$mail->Port = 587; // Porta TCP para a conexão
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; // Utiliza TLS Automaticamente se disponível
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; # Usar autenticação SMTP - Sim
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxa@gmail.com'; # Login de e-mail
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxx'; // # Password do e-mail
# Define o remetente (você)
$mail->From = "xxxxxxxxa@gmail.com"; # Seu e-mail
$mail->FromName = "Colaborador"; // Seu nome
# Define os destinatário(s)
$mail->AddAddress('xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx.pt', 'xxxxxxxx
#$mail->AddAddress('webmaster@nomedoseudominio.pt'); # Caso queira receber uma copia
$mail->AddCC('xxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.pt', 'xxxxxxx'); # Copia
#$mail->AddBCC('pessoa3@dominio.pt', 'Pessoa Nome 3'); # Cópia Oculta
# Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
$mail->IsHTML(true); # Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
#$mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-1'; # Charset da mensagem (opcional)
# Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
$mail->Subject = "Organização de Carross"; # Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Body = "Informo que está em falta um ou mais produtos na organização do carro.
<html>
                        <head>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <h2>Registo de Organização dos Carros</h2>


                          <tr>
                            <th>Colaborador: ".$col."</th><p></br>
                            <th>Produto: ".$prod."</th><p></br>
                            <th>Observação: ".$obsevacao."</th><p></br>
                            <th>Data: '".date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')."'</th><p></br>
                          </tr>

                        </body>
                        </html>";
$mail->AltBody = "Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, somente Texto! \r\n :)";

# Define os anexos (opcional)
#$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "documento.pdf"); # Insere um anexo
# Envia o e-mail
$enviado = $mail->Send(); 
# Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();
}       
}
```

O único problema que tenho, é que quando tenho mais do que um produto com valor na checkbox **não** só envia o primeiro produto a receber valor e pretendia que enviasse no email todos os produtos que receberam valor na checkbox **não**

Comment: Só adiantando, esse body do email está mal formado, você está colocando um texto antes do HTML.

Comment: @Sam, ok, pode ajudar a corrigir? Deu para entender o meu problema?

Comment: Acho que os `require` deveriam ficar antes do `for`.

Comment: @Sam, não conseguiu ver uma solução?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no que comentei  Vc está fazendo loop de require.

Comment: @Sam, o problema era mesmo esse.

Comment: @Sam é possível falar pelo chat?

Comment: No momento não estou podendo.

Answer (score 0):

No meu entendimento, acho que vc deveria fazer uma consulta e criar um loop aonde vai as informações para o cliente, assim vc pegaria todos os produtos do determinado cliente com o check **não** marcado.

Comment: sim isso é uma possibilidade, mas esse loop tem de ser feito no momento do registo, porque pretendo que só envie os produtos com check **não** no momento do registo e não os que existem na tabela da base de dados, fiz me entender?

Comment: sim, entendi, logo após essa condição if($nao != ""){ faça sua consulta pegando os campos das tabelas que vc quer, e no email faça o loop para colocar os produtos. Acho que isso resolve.